# How does the math of storing energy in a spring work in a moving frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, energy-conservation, work, spring

Consider a spring with spring constant $k$ attached at one end to a wall. When an external force stretches it by distance $l$ in the positive direction the force does work $\frac{1}{2}kl^2$ and that energy is stored in the spring as elastic potential energy.

Let the stretching take place uniformly over a time $t$ for definiteness.

If this operation is viewed by an observer moving at velocity $v$ with respect to the lab, the starting and ending position of the stretching operation will appear to be different, say $0$ and $l - vt$, but the average force exerted on the spring would remain $\frac{1}{2}kl$, which seems to make the work done (and energy stored in the spring)
$$ W = \left(\frac{1}{2}kl\right) \cdot (l - vt) \;.$$

How is this (potentially vast) difference reconciled?

Comment: I know this is a fairly elementary exercise, but it seems to be causing some confusing in the comments of another question.

Comment: @sammygerbil Hmmm ... first the answer where the comments were and then the question itself was deleted. for the record the link (10k rep only) is http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290723/.

Answer (score 1):

In the moving frame the "fixed" end of the spring moves over a distance $-vt$, always exerting the same magnitude force as that applied, but in the negative direction so the work
$$\begin{align*}
W_\text{fixed} &= \left(-\frac{1}{2} kl\right) \cdot (-vt) \\
&= +\frac{1}{2} klvt \;.
\end{align*}$$

That makes the net work done to the spring
$$W_\text{net} =  \left(\frac{1}{2}kl(l - vt)\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2} klvt\right) = \frac{1}{2} kl^2 \;,$$
just as before.

Comment: I think there is a sign mistake in the last step.

Comment: @S007 Uhm. Yep. We have to add the works.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I have a doubt. Can we just directly take the final length of spring and initial length of spring to find the net elongation seen by the moving observer ? After that just use $W= \frac{1}{2}kx^2$... where $x$ is the elongation. In any constant velocity frame the extension in the spring will be same...

Comment: @S007 Sure, you can just work the problem in the lab frame. The point of the question, however, is that the infrastructure gives you the correct answer in a moving frame as well, even though the computations of the work contributions give potentially very large answers.

Comment: I don't think the rules allow changing a sign just to make the answer come out right 8>)

Comment: @S007 wasn't working the problem in the lab frame, he was working it in the moving frame.  He correctly said that the elongation observed in the moving frame was the same as that in the lab frame.  Meanwhile, your answer to your own question still isn't correct--are you working on it?

Comment: Asking about the elongation *is* working in the lab frame: you ask "how far did the free end move relative the fixed end?" That's fair, and it is how I would find the elastic potential energy in a practical case. But the point is that *the work done by the applied force is frame dependent* and that is OK because it doesn't break anything. I've given shown that applying the definition of work in the moving frame you get the same result for the elastic potential energy in each frame despite the wildly different expressions for the work done by the applied force.

Comment: @D.Ennis He just made a sign mistake in the first step of the problem...else the logic is okay

Comment: @s007 do you mean in the first step of the answer?  I don't see it--can you help me out?

Comment: @D.Ennis The moving train exerts a force on the fixed end of the spring and therby does postive work on it and not negative whose value is \begin{align*}
W_\text{fixed} &= \frac{1}{2} kl \cdot (vt) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} klvt \;.
\end{align*}.

Comment: @D.Ennis At the time the experiment beings the fixed end is at location $0$ (this value is arbitrary) in the frame of the moving observer, by time the stretching is finished the fixed end as at $0-vt=-vt$. It went a distance $-vt$ from the moving observer's point of view while exerting an average force $+\frac{1}{2}kl$. So the work done to the spring by the fixture in the moving frame is as written. This is directly from the definition of work. Similarly for the calculation of the applied work in the moving frame done in the question.

Comment: OK. Found another sign error . The applied focer is in the positive direction, so the force from the fixture is in the negative direction. Should be sorted now.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Looks good now.  Yes, correctly done, the mathematical treatment of pseudo work leads to the true value of work done.